# Press and hold button to achieve continuously moving slides in Swiper (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

I'm trying to implement a function to press and hold next/prev buttons to make sliders change continuously (not by one by one after each click) in the Swiper plugin in Reactjs.
I was trying several solutions but still no result. Any ideas on how to make it?
Thanks!

Here is my code. Nothing special, It works great, clicks on next/prev buttons change slide. But I can't achieve how to hold these buttons to make slides changes constantly.

```
 <Swiper
            id="main-slider"
            tag="section"
            wrapperTag="ul"
            navigation
            // scrollbar={{ draggable: true }}
            slidesPerView={1}
            grabCursor={true}
            onSlideChange={(swiper) => {
              slideChanged(swiper.activeIndex);
            }}
            initialSlide={currGame || 1}
          >
            {allGames?.map((slide, index) => (
              <SwiperSlide key={slide.event_id} tag="li">
....... 
</SwiperSlide>
```

Comment: Please, share the code of what you've tried so far and where you got stuck

Comment: @AndreaOlivato I pasted code sample at my post